# Hadoop Reducer unable to accumulate all values in one iteration

Tags: hadoop, loops

I have a basic scenario in Hadoop:

All mappers send all values to the **same** key. Therefore all values end up on the **same** reducer.

However, when I iterate the values in the reducer, the iterator does not process all of the entries.

For example, I could have the following code:

```
while (values.hasNext())
{
  result = result + values.next().toString() + "\n";
}
// Assume, that all values sent to this reducer is now in the 'result' variable
do_important_stuff(result);
```

I would like accumulate the values associated, and then process the data in the function, 'do_important_stuff()'. But I am not able to do so - the while-loop breaks too soon.

Am I missing a crucial point about Hadoop? Is my assumption wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by assigning references instead of values.

With an ArrayList as accumulator and cloning of every value, Ex:

```
result = new ArrayList<Text>();
while (values.hasNext())
{
  result.add(new Text(values.next());
}
```

the iterator would terminate with all the desired values in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You are controlling the loop with

```
values.hasNext()
```

but are advancing with

```
rows.next()
```

Are `rows` and `values` the same object?  I suspect a typo. :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction :) I tried to boil away all the context-sensitive parts from my own code

Comment: When there is only one key for the whole job, is there a nice way to make the job more efficient? Using a combiner will definitely help. Since there is only one key emitted by the map task, only one key/value pair will be sent per map task to the reducer. Also, if the key can be fine grained the reduce tasks can be distributed.